# Dyck paths with extra diagonals from valleys (Laser construction)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to create a [Dyck path](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html) in Latex with two additional features. First, I would like to number all the East step except(!) for the last one. Secondly, for each valley (that is, an East step that is followed by a North step), I would like to draw "lasers" which would be lines that are parallel to the diagonal and that stops once it reaches the Dyck path. This is similar, but not exactly the same as the "laser construction" in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07198.pdf) paper. See e.g. Figure 6.

I already have some code to obtain a Dyck path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\NEpath}[4]{
    \fill[white!25]  (#1) rectangle +(#2,#3);
    \fill[fill=white]
    (#1)
    \foreach \dir in {#4}{
        \ifnum\dir=0
        -- ++(1,0)
        \else
        -- ++(0,1)
        \fi
    } |- (#1);
    \draw[help lines] (#1) grid +(#2,#3);
    \draw[dashed] (#1) -- +(#3,#3);
    \coordinate (prev) at (#1);
    \foreach \dir in {#4}{
        \ifnum\dir=0
        \coordinate (dep) at (1,0);
        \else
        \coordinate (dep) at (0,1);
        \fi
        \draw[line width=2pt,-stealth] (prev) -- ++(dep) coordinate (prev);
    };
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \NEpath{0,0}{6}{6}{1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following picture.

[image]

Whereas I would like to obtain something like

[image]

Is it be possible to modify my existing code to obtain what I desire? If not, is there an alternative approach?

Comment: How about adding those paths manually?

Comment: Btw, as it is an arXiv document, you may find the source code of the file, thus you can find the code for the picture

Comment: @JouleV I am unfortunately not very good with tikz - what do you mean by adding the paths manually? Also, the image in the pdf is not done in tikz but rather attached as a pdf.

Comment: What I mean is that you can add the lines "by hand" inside the `tikzpicture`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun, something that adds the numbers and laser lines automatically. The laser lines are drawn automatically according to your clarified prescription. The strategy is to look at the elements of the list that are ahead and check whether or not they fulfill certain criteria. The integer `\vtest` tests if the current point is a "valley", in which case it is `10`, and the other integers are constructed similarly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\newcounter{DyckHsteps}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{count list/.code 2 args={\foreach \XX [count=\YY] in {#1}
{\xdef#2{\YY}}},Dyck arrow/.style={ultra thick,-stealth},
laser/.style={draw=blue},
Dyck path/.style={count list={#1}{\DyckSteps},
/utils/exec=\setcounter{DyckHsteps}{0},insert path={%
foreach \XX [count=\YY,remember=\YY as \LastY (initially 0)]in {#1}
{\ifnum\XX=0
edge[Dyck arrow] ++(1,0) ++(1,0) coordinate(Dyck-\YY)
\ifnum\YY<\DyckSteps
(Dyck-\LastY) -- (Dyck-\YY) node[midway,above]{\stepcounter{DyckHsteps}\number\value{DyckHsteps}}
\fi
\else
edge[Dyck arrow] ++(0,1) ++(0,1) coordinate(Dyck-\YY)
\fi
\pgfextra{\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\vtest}{0}\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ftest}{0}\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\htest}{0}\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{1}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\RestSteps}{\DyckSteps-\YY}
\ifnum\YY>1
 \ifnum\RestSteps>1
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ftest}{{#1}[\YY+1]+{#1}[\YY]*10} % should be 10
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\vtest}{{#1}[\YY-1]+10*{#1}[\YY]} % valley test
 \fi
 \ifnum\RestSteps>3
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\htest}{pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+3])+pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+2])
 +pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+1])+pow(-1,{#1}[\YY])+ifthenelse({#1}[\YY-1]==1,11,0))}
 \fi
 \ifnum\RestSteps>5
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\itest}{pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+5])+
 pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+4])+pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+3])+pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+2])
 +pow(-1,{#1}[\YY+1])+pow(-1,{#1}[\YY])+ifthenelse({#1}[\YY-1]==1,11,0)
 +ifthenelse({#1}[\YY-2]==1,11,0)}
 \fi
\fi%\typeout{\YY:\RestSteps:\ftest,\htest,\itest,\vtest}
}
\ifnum\vtest=10 
 %(Dyck-\YY) node[blue,fill,circle,inner sep=2pt]{}(Dyck-\YY)
 \ifnum\itest=0
  (Dyck-\YY) edge[laser] ++(3,3) (Dyck-\YY)
 \fi
 \ifnum\htest=1100
  (Dyck-\YY) edge[laser] ++(-2,-2) (Dyck-\YY)
 \fi
 \ifnum\ftest=10
  (Dyck-\YY) edge[laser] ++(1,1) (Dyck-\YY)
 \fi
\fi 
}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) grid (6,6);
 \draw (0,0) [Dyck path={1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! But (at least in my case) the lasers should only go from the valleys and up-right. I imagine one could modify the code to get this tho.

Comment: @JoakimUhlin They go right-up, don't they?

Comment: True but they also go down-left in your case. You can compare this to my picture. For example, there should not be a laser between (0,0) and (3,3) but there should be one between (3,3) and (6,6).

Comment: @JoakimUhlin Hmm, sorry, I do not understand these prescriptions. Whether it is up-right or down-left is only a matter of perspective, isn't it? From the point (0,0) you can go up-right to (3,3), or you can go from (3,3) down-left to (0,0), the result looks identical to me.

Comment: Perhaps the example is a bit confusing because it is symmetric around the antidiagonal which need not to be the case in general. But the point I am trying to make here is that if we are standing at a valley at coordinates (i,j), then the laser should go from (i,j) to (i+d,j+d), where d is the smallest positive integer so that (i+d,j+d) lies on the Dyck path. However, the laser should not go to any vertex (i-e,j-e), where e is a positive integer (unless there is another valley at some vertex (i-e,j-e)). I'm sorry if I am still being confusing. I am thankfull for your answer nonetheless!

Comment: If this answer is still confusing I think it will be more clear if you compare my picture to yours.

Comment: @JoakimUhlin Sorry, it is confusing, simply because if I apply these prescriptions to the point `(0,0)` then I get a line that goes to `(3,3).` And unfortunately the comparison does not help much because all I am able to do is to implement some prescriptions in the code, but this obviously does not work if I do not understand the prescriptions.

Comment: @JoakimUhlin I you only want to remove the "offending" laser line, just replace `\ifnum\YY>5` by `\ifnum\YY>6`.

Comment: Ah, maybe what is confusing you then is that a valley is vertex where the previous step is an East step and the next step is a North step. So the vertex at (0,0) is not a valley. In fact, the valleys are (1,2), (3,3) and (4,5).

Comment: @JoakimUhlin I updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

With the help from JouleV, I managed to do solve this but I am leaving this as an answer for people who might be interested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\NEpath}[4]{
    \fill[white!25]  (#1) rectangle +(#2,#3);
    \fill[fill=white]
    (#1)
    \foreach \dir in {#4}{
        \ifnum\dir=0
        -- ++(1,0)
        \else
        -- ++(0,1)
        \fi
    } |- (#1);
    \draw[help lines] (#1) grid +(#2,#3);
    \draw[dashed] (#1) -- +(#3,#3);
    \coordinate (prev) at (#1);
    \foreach \dir in {#4}{
        \ifnum\dir=0
        \coordinate (dep) at (1,0);
        \else
        \coordinate (dep) at (0,1);
        \fi
        \draw[line width=2pt,-stealth] (prev) -- ++(dep) coordinate (prev);
    };
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \NEpath{0,0}{6}{6}{1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0};
    \draw (1,2) -- +(1,1);
    \draw (3,3.1) -- +(2.9,2.9);
    \draw (4,5) -- +(1,1);
    \node at (0.5, 2.5)   {1};
    \node at (1.5, 3.5)   {2};
    \node at (2.5, 3.5)   {3};
    \node at (3.5, 5.5)   {4};
    \node at (4.5, 6.5)   {5};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following the picture

[image]

Perhaps not the most pretty solution and quite mechanical but it works for my purposes. However, It would still be interesting to have a more general solution so that I would not need to draw lines and numbers manually.

Comment: I think this is going to be the most general solution unless someone comes up with a tikz package for drawing your specific kind of graph/path.

Answer (score 4):

First, congratulations for figuring out everything by yourself. I upvoted your answer.

This answer is a slight improvement of your answer in the position of the nodes (the numbers). I use option `above` to have a better space between the number and the line below it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\NEpath}[4]{
    \fill[white!25]  (#1) rectangle +(#2,#3);
    \fill[fill=white]
    (#1)
    \foreach \dir in {#4}{
        \ifnum\dir=0
        -- ++(1,0)
        \else
        -- ++(0,1)
        \fi
    } |- (#1);
    \draw[help lines] (#1) grid +(#2,#3);
    \draw[dashed] (#1) -- +(#3,#3);
    \coordinate (prev) at (#1);
    \foreach \dir in {#4}{
        \ifnum\dir=0
        \coordinate (dep) at (1,0);
        \else
        \coordinate (dep) at (0,1);
        \fi
        \draw[line width=2pt,-stealth] (prev) -- ++(dep) coordinate (prev);
    };
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \NEpath{0,0}{6}{6}{1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0};
    \draw (1,2) -- +(1,1);
    \draw (3,3.1) -- +(2.9,2.9);
    \draw (4,5) -- +(1,1);
    \node[above=2pt] at (0.5, 2)   {1};
    \node[above=2pt] at (1.5, 3)   {2};
    \node[above=2pt] at (2.5, 3)   {3};
    \node[above=2pt] at (3.5, 5)   {4};
    \node[above=2pt] at (4.5, 6)   {5};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]